# Can not load file or assembly on SharePoint 2013 Farm Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We've developed a farm solution for SharePoint 2013 which uses third party dll's like Newtonsoft.Json that is deployed under WebApplication Scope instead of GAC. There are other vendors who have already deployed farm solutions under WebApplication Scope that references the same dll files, but of a much older version and have no plans on updating them.
As a solution to prevent our app from overwriting common dll's like Newtonsoft.Json we've updated our Package Manifest to have the dll's deploy to a custom directory on the webserver's bin folder.
But when executed we get the following error:

**Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

How do we go about solving this? Any help appreciated.

Screenshots for reference:

[image: Project Reference]

[image: Reference Manager]

[image: Package Manifest]

Comment: Please have a try to set 'Copy Local' to true to make sure the dll is in output folder as this solution will be deployed.

Comment: I've already set 'Copy to Local' to true. I see it in the bin folder under the 'Custom' Directory. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was that **CLR** (Common Language Runtime) could not locate and bind the referenced assemblies since it's placed in a custom directory.

Ended up registering the custom directory in the **web.config** file:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin\Custom"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

To learn more about probing, see the official Microsoft documentation on [Probing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the original local dll from solution.

Then try to install the Newtonsoft Json Package using Nuget Command:

install-package newtonsoft.json

Rebuild and deploy the solution to see if it works.